# Android - Show dial intent

Tags: android

I tried below code to get a number and show dial intent to user, it works fine in android 2.3.3 but in android 4.3 emulator when I use it, it shows a alert dialog having 2 buttons, `Close`  and `Add to contacts`, how can I show dial intent in android 4?

```
public void callnumber(String st) {
    Intent dialIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
    dialIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + st));
    startActivity(dialIntent);
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no app to handle this intent in your device.

Comment: still having the same problem

Comment: try with real ph number not 0000000

Comment: You are trying in tab that cannot make call try in phone.

Comment: I do not want to make call, I want the user to see the phone on dial intent

Comment: I have tried and its problem in tab.. try in phone it will work.

Comment: there are no app to handle this intent in your device.

Answer (score 2):

Use `Intent.ACTION_DIAL` instead of `Intent.ACTION_VIEW`

Comment: still having the same problem

Comment: what device you tried on, dose the 4.0 device support calls ?

Comment: I have tried exact your code on (Galaxy S1 2.3, Galaxy S2 4.0.3, Nexus4 4.4.2 and Nexus4 emulator 4.1.2) and it works

Comment: now thats weird, on emulater Android 4.3 shows the dialog. i dont have a real device with 4.3, you need to try it on a one.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:**

```
private void performDial(String numberString) {
    if (!numberString.equals("")) {
       Uri number = Uri.parse("tel:" + numberString);
       Intent dial = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, number);
       startActivity(dial);
    }
}
```

Comment: I do not want to make call, I want the user to see the phone on dial intent

Comment: I tried this, it will make call automatically, I want to show the phone number and then user decide to call or not

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use `Intent.ACTION_CALL`

Comment: I do not want to make call, I want the user to see the phone on dial intent

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Intent dialIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
dialIntent.setData(Uri.parse(st));
startActivity(dialIntent);
```

It will open dialler.

Hope it helps.

Comment: still having the same problem

Answer (score 0):

```
String number = "tel:" + txtcall.getText().toString().trim();
            Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL,
                    Uri.parse(number));
            viewContactInfo.startActivity(callIntent);
```

use this..i think this is working fine in 2.3.3 and also android 4.

Comment: I do not want to make call, I want the user to see the phone on dial intent